# SharePoint 2013 Search consuming much disk space on C drive

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search

I found many questions and there answer related to issue I am having. But I did not get exact answer.

I can see lot of C drive space is consume by Search index/logs on Application server. I am running Full Crawl 1 time in day and incremental crawl after each 5 min.

I have to resolve this issue on urgent basis. Please assist me.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot of TreeSize so we can exactly see which folders cause most disk-usage?

Comment: Please indicate the size of the content you are crawling as well, if you are crawling content that will consume disk space. You can move the index if that is the problem.

Comment: Hi, did you ever resolved this?